# JQuery - using value from one script within another?

Tags: jquery

My page loads multiple Jquery plugins and scripts.

Within one of the plugin pages there is a function and within that I've created a new variable with an associated value.

I've created it as : `currentPoint = $(currentRow).attr('data-point')`

In my custom script I'd like to use that value, but I can't seem to get access to it. I'm trying to access it as: `console.log (currentPoint)`  all I returned is `undefined`.

Is this possible ?
Thanks

Comment: Should be `var currentPoint = $(currentRow).attr('data-point');`

Comment: Too many unknowns. Provide more code context. See [mcve]

Comment: I'm using a plugin called tablednd, as I drag the table rows around I 'd like to get the `data-point` from the row I've just passed.  I can get this within tablednd so I assigned that as a value to currentPoint.

Comment: If variable is same scope as `console.log(currentPoint)` than you can use it, otherwise you can't access it.

Comment: tablednd has a onDrop function. When called I'm trying to use currentPoint, but all it returns is : `main.js:142 Uncaught ReferenceError: currentPoint is not defined(…)`

Comment: @Justinas if I console.log it within the plugin page I can see it, but not from my js page